# Getting UnsatisfiedDependencyException during IBM Liberty server start up

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, websphere-liberty

I am getting the UnsatisfiedDependencyException during the IBM Liberty server start up. Even though spring beans are available in spring configuration files. It is throwing error. Can you please let me know where I made mistakes.Below is the full stack trace for the error. I am using websphere 8.5.5.8 version

```
ltListableBeanFactory] [-] Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'preProcess6266001TransBean': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mEbcContext': Error creating bean with name 'ebcfwk.ebcContext': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ebcfwk.ebcContext': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?  
 2017-04-13 11:20:05,834 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [-] Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'becBatchGroupTrans' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/GIT/RIXJava7New1/EBCIRIX01/ebcirix01_as/ebcirix01/target/ebcirix01-1.41.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/ebcrixcommon01-1.41.0-SNAPSHOT-classes.jar!/ebcrixcommon01-batchContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ebcfwk.ebcContext': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?  
 2017-04-13 11:20:05,835 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [-] Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'preProcess6351001TransBean': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mEbcContext': Error creating bean with name 'ebcfwk.ebcContext': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ebcfwk.ebcContext': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?  
 2017-04-13 11:20:05,835 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [-] Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'becBatchGroupTrans' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/GIT/RIXJava7New1/EBCIRIX01/ebcirix01_as/ebcirix01/target/ebcirix01-1.41.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/ebcrixcommon01-1.41.0-SNAPSHOT-classes.jar!/ebcrixcommon01-batchContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ebcfwk.ebcContext': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?  
 2017-04-13 11:20:05,836 INFO  [com.ikea.ebcframework.internal.services.EbbManagerPropsInitializedEbcContext] [-]   EBCContext - [ebcName="EBCIRIX01"], [locality="Local"], [virtualDomain=""], [hostName="com.ikea.ebcframework.internal.config.HostName@7f8fa2f1"], DefaultUserAndRequestProfile{[userId="default"][userIdRegion="Local"][clientId=""][originator="EBCIRIX01"][ebcRoles=""][languageCode="en"][countryCode="SE"][timeZone="GMT"][runAsUid="EBCIRIX01"][locality="Local"][virtualDomain=""][msgId=""][msgIdSeq="0"][invocationStyle="INVOCATION_SYNCH"][deliveryStyle="BEST_EFFORT"][bsName=""][hostName=""][ebcInstance=""][ebcName="EBCIRIX01"]}  
 2017-04-13 11:20:05,838 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [-] Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'preProcess5970005TransBean': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mEbcContext': Error creating bean with name 'ebcfwk.ebcContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ebcfwk.ebcContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException  
 2017-04-13 11:20:05,930 INFO  [com.ikea.ebcframework.internal.services.EbbManagerPropsInitializedEbcContext] [-]   EBCContext - [ebcName="EBCIRIX01"], [locality="Local"], [virtualDomain=""], [hostName="com.ikea.ebcframework.internal.config.HostName@7f8fa2f1"], DefaultUserAndRequestProfile{[userId="default"][userIdRegion="Local"][clientId=""][originator="EBCIRIX01"][ebcRoles=""][languageCode="en"][countryCode="SE"][timeZone="GMT"][runAsUid="EBCIRIX01"][locality="Local"][virtualDomain=""][msgId=""][msgIdSeq="0"][invocationStyle="INVOCATION_SYNCH"][deliveryStyle="BEST_EFFORT"][bsName=""][hostName=""][ebcInstance=""][ebcName="EBCIRIX01"]}  
 2017-04-13 11:20:05,931 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [-] Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'becBatchGroupTrans' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/GIT/RIXJava7New1/EBCIRIX01/ebcirix01_as/ebcirix01/target/ebcirix01-1.41.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/ebcrixcommon01-1.41.0-SNAPSHOT-classes.jar!/ebcrixcommon01-batchContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ebcfwk.ebcContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException  
 2017-04-13 11:20:05,936 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [-] Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'becBatchGroupTrans' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/GIT/RIXJava7New1/EBCIRIX01/ebcirix01_as/ebcirix01/target/ebcirix01-1.41.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/ebcrixcommon01-1.41.0-SNAPSHOT-classes.jar!/ebcrixcommon01-batchContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ebcfwk.ebcContext': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?  
 2017-04-13 11:20:05,939 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [-] Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'becBatchGroupTrans' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/GIT/RIXJava7New1/EBCIRIX01/ebcirix01_as/ebcirix01/target/ebcirix01-1.41.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/ebcrixcommon01-1.41.0-SNAPSHOT-classes.jar!/ebcrixcommon01-batchContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ebcfwk.ebcContext': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?  
 2017-04-13 11:20:05,942 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [-] Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'becBatchGroupTrans' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/GIT/RIXJava7New1/EBCIRIX01/ebcirix01_as/ebcirix01/target/ebcirix01-1.41.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/ebcrixcommon01-1.41.0-SNAPSHOT-classes.jar!/ebcrixcommon01-batchContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ebcfwk.ebcContext': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?  
 2017-04-13 11:20:05,945 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [-] Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'becBatchGroupTrans' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/GIT/RIXJava7New1/EBCIRIX01/ebcirix01_as/ebcirix01/target/ebcirix01-1.41.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/ebcrixcommon01-1.41.0-SNAPSHOT-classes.jar!/ebcrixcommon01-batchContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ebcfwk.ebcContext': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?  
 2017-04-13 11:20:05,947 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [-] Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'becBatchGroupTrans' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/GIT/RIXJava7New1/EBCIRIX01/ebcirix01_as/ebcirix01/target/ebcirix01-1.41.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/ebcrixcommon01-1.41.0-SNAPSHOT-classes.jar!/ebcrixcommon01-batchContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ebcfwk.ebcContext': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?  
 2017-04-13 11:20:05,950 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [-] Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'becBatchGroupTrans' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/GIT/RIXJava7New1/EBCIRIX01/ebcirix01_as/ebcirix01/target/ebcirix01-1.41.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/ebcrixcommon01-1.41.0-SNAPSHOT-classes.jar!/ebcrixcommon01-batchContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ebcfwk.ebcContext': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?  
 2017-04-13 11:20:05,951 INFO  [com.ikea.ebcframework.internal.services.EbbManagerPropsInitializedEbcContext] [-]   EBCContext - [ebcName="EBCIRIX01"], [locality="Local"], [virtualDomain=""], [hostName="com.ikea.ebcframework.internal.config.HostName@7f8fa2f1"], DefaultUserAndRequestProfile{[userId="default"][userIdRegion="Local"][clientId=""][originator="EBCIRIX01"][ebcRoles=""][languageCode="en"][countryCode="SE"][timeZone="GMT"][runAsUid="EBCIRIX01"][locality="Local"][virtualDomain=""][msgId=""][msgIdSeq="0"][invocationStyle="INVOCATION_SYNCH"][deliveryStyle="BEST_EFFORT"][bsName=""][hostName=""][ebcInstance=""][ebcName="EBCIRIX01"]}  
 2017-04-13 11:20:05,952 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [-] Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'preProcess6351001TransBean': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mEbcContext': Error creating bean with name 'ebcfwk.ebcContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ebcfwk.ebcContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException  
 2017-04-13 11:20:05,957 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [-] Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'preProcess6351001TransBean': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mEbcContext': Error creating bean with name 'ebcfwk.ebcContext': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ebcfwk.ebcContext': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?  
 2017-04-13 11:20:05,992 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [-] Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'preProcess6351001TransBean': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mEbcContext': Error creating bean with name 'ebcfwk.ebcContext': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ebcfwk.ebcContext': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?  
 2017-04-13 11:20:05,998 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [-] Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'preProcess6351001TransBean': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mEbcContext': Error creating bean with name 'ebcfwk.ebcContext': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ebcfwk.ebcContext': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?  
 2017-04-13 11:20:06,003 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [-] Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'preProcess6351001TransBean': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mEbcContext': Error creating bean with name 'ebcfwk.ebcContext': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ebcfwk.ebcContext': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?  
 2017-04-13 11:20:06,008 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [-] Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'preProcess6351001TransBean': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mEbcContext': Error creating bean with name 'ebcfwk.ebcContext': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ebcfwk.ebcContext': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?  
 2017-04-13 11:20:06,013 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [-] Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'preProcess6351001TransBean': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mEbcContext': Error creating bean with name 'ebcfwk.ebcContext': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ebcfwk.ebcContext': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?  
 2017-04-13 11:20:06,014 INFO  [com.ikea.ebcframework.internal.services.EbbManagerPropsInitializedEbcContext] [-]   EBCContext - [ebcName="EBCIRIX01"], [locality="Local"], [virtualDomain=""], [hostName="com.ikea.ebcframework.internal.config.HostName@7f8fa2f1"], DefaultUserAndRequestProfile{[userId="default"][userIdRegion="Local"][clientId=""][originator="EBCIRIX01"][ebcRoles=""][languageCode="en"][countryCode="SE"][timeZone="GMT"][runAsUid="EBCIRIX01"][locality="Local"][virtualDomain=""][msgId=""][msgIdSeq="0"][invocationStyle="INVOCATION_SYNCH"][deliveryStyle="BEST_EFFORT"][bsName=""][hostName=""][ebcInstance=""][ebcName="EBCIRIX01"]}
```

Comment: error messages indicate a NPE from your bean init method.  Have you checked where the NPE is coming from?

Comment: This error is coming after migrating from jdk 6 to jdk 7. Spring version we are using is 4.3.0

Comment: I meant what is the stack trace of the NPE?

Comment: NPE is coming because of jar files are missing, in war file jar is available.While deploying the application into server jars are missing.I dont why jars are missing?